# Zend Framework 2 Authentication/ACL via JSON requests

Tags: json, authentication, zend-framework2

I understand how Database Table Authentication or Digest Authentication or HTTP Authentication works given the examples provided in the documentation. I would like to authenticate users to my application using Zend's \Authentication\Adapter, but am unsure how to do that by accessing a JSON Server rather than a local database.

Our users will pass their credentials into the application via a web post, and the application will send any and all request to a separate service via JSON to authenticate, query, etc. I have no problem hooking into the JSON Server, and writing the requests, etc. for that.

What I'd like to do is use Zend's built in Authentication mechanism to hook into the results returned by the JSON Server. Is there a way to do that using JSON rather than Database Table Authentication or Digest Authentication, etc.?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your own adapter, implementing:

```
Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface
```

Take a look at the other adapters for instiration

Comment: Perfect. That's what I'll do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.